# Docker MySQL Permissions with Volumes

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose

I'm trying to get log files from mysql enabled and mounted so we can parse the logs.

Running docker and docker-compose on a Linux system:

Trying to mount a custom configuration for mysql. I have a `conf.d/custom.cnf` that I mount

```
[mysqld_safe]
log_error=/var/lib/mysql/log/mysql_error.log

[mysqld]
log_error=/var/lib/mysql/log/mysql_error.log

general_log_file        = /var/lib/mysql/log/mysql.log
general_log             = 1

log_slow_queries       = /var/lib/mysql/log/mysql-slow.log
long_query_time = 2
log-queries-not-using-indexes
```

with my docker-compose

```
version: '2'
services:
  mysql:
    env_file: "env/mysql.env"
    container_name: mysql
    image: mysql:5.7.13
    logging:
      driver: json-file
      options:
        max-size: 50m
    network_mode: host
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    volumes:
      - "./mysql_data:/var/lib/mysql"
      - "./config/mysql/conf.d:/etc/mysql/conf.d"
```

But it doesn't start MySQL. When I go inside the container and run `mysqld` it just exits with no log message.

When I run `/etc/init.d/mysql start` I see error messages about permissions. Stuff like

`(Errcode: 13 - Permission denied)`

and

`2017-10-06T14:55:48.688986Z 0 [ERROR] --initialize specified but the data directory exists and is not writable. Aborting.`

What's the proper way to do this? I'm hoping I don't have to run any permission changes... And I'm sure this is a very common thing people do with MySQL containers?

Comment: Does `./mysql_data` exist next to your compose file? What are the permissions? I would start there. Why do you hope you don't have to change any permissions?

Comment: yes mysql_data exists next to my compose file. I was hoping I could just run docker-compose up and it would just work, but am i supposed to already have that directory with permissions for a "mysql" user to access it? sort of strange to have to have a folder already existing with specific permissions - especially since i'm trying to manage it with git

Comment: Try removing the directory and see if Docker creates it.